# Downloading a file with MailChimp

Tags: mailchimp

I've got a simple embedded MailChimp form (email addresss + submit button) on my site. For now, clicking on submit allows users to subscribe to my MailChimp list.

What I want is that when the user subscribes, he/she automatically receives an email containing a link to some PDF file. And that's it, I won't send anything else to this user.

So I guess this is not done using campaigns, because campaigns are emails sent from the admin to subscribers at specified times. By contrast, I want the user to receive the email containing the file immediately and only once.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can't do that with email campaign. But you can do it uising the "welcome email".

1. When a new user subscribe to your list a "welcome email" can automatically be sent to him.
2. You can personalize the content of that email and it's the right place for you to put your html link to the pdf file that the user can download.